# RequestBody pass attribute value into collection

Tags: java, json, spring

Assume the following JSON:

```
{
 "attr_A": "val_A",
 "array_A": [{
    "attr_B": "val_B"
  }]
}
```

and the following two classes:

```
public class ClassA {
  List<ClassB> children = new ArrayList();
}
```

```
public class ClassB {
  String val_A;
  String val_B;
}
```

The attriute `attr_A` defines a common value for all objects defined in `array_A`. Now I have a REST Controller defined in my Spring project, that expects this JSON and should parse it into the aforementioned classes.

My ultimate goal is to eventually persists the ClassB object into the DB with both values:

```
TABLE ClassB(attr_A VARCHAR, attr_B VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Given the ultimate goal, why complicate the parsing and make it less natural?  A new programmer would likely be confused, or think `val_A` could have different values.  Consider changing the persistence layer instead of changing the natural class layout.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of change to persistence layer do you mean. I am fairly new to Spring and my Persistance layer consists of a single interface `ClassBRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassB, String>`.

Comment: I meant the persistence layer should handle `val_A` even though it's in `ClassA`, and not duplicated in `ClassB`.

Comment: The pojo class pattern should be according to json format. The pojo you create doesn't look correct.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks. I realized I misunderstood the DTO pattern. I have made a separate classes (ClassADTO, ClassBDTO) for objects as received by the HTTP request and then created a mapper to map them onto the Entity classes used by the DB (ClassA, ClassB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a request class as follows:

```
public class RequestDto{
   String attr_A;
   List<ArrayClass> array_A;
   // getters and setters
}

public class ArrayClass{ 
   String attr_B;
   // getters and setters
}
```

Use requestDto as the @RequestBody.

```
public Response method(@RequestBody RequestDto request)
```

Once you have the request object in the controller. You can loop through the array_A and save the value as you wish.

```
String attr_A = request.getAttr_A();
List<ArrayClass> arrayClassList = request.getArray_A();
for(ArrayClass arrayClass : arrayClasslist){
    String attr_B = arrayClass.getAttr_B();
    saveTableB(attr_A, attr_B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Receive the JSON as JSONbject or JsonNode or whatever of the sort your Spring configuration will give you, and write by yourself some code that will copy the fields to fit in a ClassA.